# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound - error when sending parameter

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets

We have the following situation

```
    <a href="<c:url value="/inventory"/>">Example 1</a>
    <a href="<c:url value="/inventory/?type=removed"/>">Example 2</a>
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "inventory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printInventoryPage(
            ModelMap model,
            @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type) {

        return "inventory";
    }
```

"Example 1" works great, but if i clicked "Example 2" generate errors like this

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/exampleproject/inventory/resources/js/jquery.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

Of course, error applies to all resources like css, javascripts etc.

In addition to any web page, I including all resources using the `<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>`

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put one extra `/` at end of URI in "/inventory/?type=removed". Simply write "/inventory?type=removed".

You map the controller method to "inventory". IMHO it would be more correct to map it to "/inventory". But "/inventory/" is another URL.

If for any reasons, you need the method to answer both, declare it that way :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/inventory", "/inventory/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printInventoryPage( ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inventory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printInventoryPage(...)
```

and remove `/` from url in JSP before `?`

```
<a href="<c:url value="/inventory?type=removed"/>">Example 2</a>
```